# VSCode not autoformating R lintr suggestions

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, format, lintr

I am trying to figure out how to have easy autoformat for my R code in VS Code. Seems like a lot of the other languages can use extensions like Prettier and ESlint to solve the common formatting issues but I cannot find something comparable for R. When I get a lintr warning the only quick fixes I have are to disable the linter.

[image: Lintr warning]

[image: quick fix options]

Anyone have any tips or tricks for solving this? Ultimate goal is to code with autoformatting enabled as I go or upon save.

I have tried different settings in languageserver but cannot get it right. I also code in multiple lanauges so want the setting to be language specific not workspace specific.

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore specific `lintr` rules? If so the way to do this is with a `.lintr` file, either in your project directory or globally. See [Using lintr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/vignettes/lintr.html).

Comment: I am asking to auto accept the lintr suggestion.. like if it tells me to fix the indentation to 2 space not 4 I want to say Okay and then it fixes it. Extensions like prettier do this

Comment: Are you using the VS Code R extension? If so it should format on save. Are you seeing any changes when you save? If not, if you press ctrl+shift+p and select Format Document With, do any R formatters come up?